# Optimizing Heavy content and data based website to mobile responsive

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, information-architecture, responsive-design, optimisation

I was working on a product which deals with data of companies where there are lot of views and lot of data.
At this point my client wanted it to be responsive on mobile and tabs and ipads.
How do i make it responsive.
Should i remove some elements from website and optimize it to mobile,tablets or what would be the solution.
Has anyone else faced this type of solution.

Comment: Can you show any comps? Or what this could look like? Usually when you have a lot of information, you *usually* have a list view, where it shows you all companies, but at that view, you only show the most important information (so out of 100 data points, only show the top 5, as an example). Then in the individual record view, you show all of the information, but at that moment you are only viewing one company at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Content display has to follow a mobile first philosophy. However, I would recommend looking at Google analytics first to understand if users who will see this content are using a mobile device. if they are, you want to make sure mobile content is not a "subset" of desktop content. Try not to remove elements on mobile.

Like someone said- cards are a good philosophy- they are very mobile friendly.

Comment: Why isn't content a subset on mobile? Space doesn't allow for all information to be present all the time. You have to shift was is shown on mobile because the users viewing it are on a different mind set. Usually if you are viewing information on your phone, you are on the go.

Comment: If I can speak on Saurabh's behalf, the primary content should not be masked because the form factor is challenging. Tertiary and possibly even secondary components can be minimized, but the primary content must remain. This assumes that the view in question is even relevant on mobile (which in some cases it is not).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you must redesign the whole thing into a mobile view (medium or small). You should remove some elements, aggregate functions and so on.
A more specific question and a mockup would be GREATLY useful

Comment: So we have a dashboard which has all data of all companies/startups around the world.It was currently a website but now the plan was to make website responsive around all the devices and we are also working on a native apps. Should we keep mobile website or should we make it only app or what is the other best thing that we could do

Comment: I understand your problem, but as you can imagine, there is no a perfect soution. You should post a more specific question about a topic. In this way you are just asking "I have a site, how can i make it mobile friendly?". Nobody can answer this without knowing the budget, the constraints, the overall project, the needs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of content. If it's a dashboard type display, I think the easiest way to create a responsive design is to break up the UI elements into modules/groups. There's a reason 'tiles' and 'cards' are very popular these days. You can lay them out in a manageable way on many screen sizes. A desktop can display a grid. As the screen shrinks the columns are reduced until on mobile it's effectively a list.

Without designs (current design or prototypes of reactive designs) or any more idea of what the "data" consists of or how it's displayed to users, there's not much help anyone can give.